# optim - setting a common contraint for multiple parameters

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I a looking to set a common constraint to a subset of my parameters:

```
c2 <- 2
nFeatures = 6
W2 <- rep(1,nFeatures)
w2 <- W2/sum(W2)
fguess2 <- 0.3
startParms2 <- c(c2,fguess2,w2)
names(startParms2) <- c("c2", "fguess", 
   "w21","w22","w23","w24","w25","w26") 


xout2 <- optim(par=startParms2, fn=rmsd, 
   data1=mydata2, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
    lower = rep(0,8), 
    upper = c(Inf,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
print(xout2)
```

Currently, all 6 parameters belonging to the vector `w2` are constrained to a individual maximum of 1. 
What I would like to do is to constrain the sum of these 6 parameters to 1 (while the remaining 2 parameters keep their current constraints).

Comment: You can encode the constrain into the objective function. Then you will have to optimize only 5 parameters... - However, without a MCVE it is difficult to say more https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: in principle you can use `constrOptim()`, but I suspect you really are trying to fit a composition parameter (all parameters bound in 0<p<1 and sum(p)==1), in which case you will be better off working with a softmax/Aitchison transformation